# Corrupted Textures?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On occasion, all grass and stone blocks will just disappear. I can still walk on them, but basically everything except wood and water is invisible. I first started having this problem in a modded world. Which I thought was normal, or to be expected because I was running a lot of mods.

But then it happened in a vanilla survival world. When it had happened both times I had been playing in those worlds for several weeks and thought the engine might just get tired at that point. But then it happened in a creative world, only a few days old. Also, it's happened in a swamp biome all three times.

I can fix it easily with F3+A, but I'm just curious as to how and why this happens. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: What mod were you using and do you have any texture packs equipped?

Comment: You have some text in the top left of that screenshot. Is that Optifine or some other mod? Try if it also happens without any mods.

Comment: In that screenshot I was using Optifine for 1.14.4, Vanilla Tweaks resource pack and a pack to make the menus dark theme.

Comment: I got some weird glitches like that in 1.12.2 on an lan server. I was walking around and i got a huge lag spike and was glitched in a leaf block. I could not break it because i was lagged somewhere I wasn’t supposed to be. I did /Kill and when i respawned i had permanent x-ray vision. It was super annoying and i dont know why it happened, it was weird.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know what Minecraft you were playing. I've had major graphic bugs in the new 1.15 version.

Most likely though, it is a graphics driver issue. If you know your graphics driver is the latest and greatest then I would suspect you are playing in 1.15 and experiencing graphic bugs. But if you are on an older computer and you have not updated the graphics driver yourself then it might be that. Computer manufacturers like HP stop updating their version of drivers for specific computers after a couple years, so the owner has to go to the Intel site (for example) and deal with it themselves.